# A word for not ones own

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

Is there a word to describe something that is not our own?

For instance: 
The thoughts I was having were not my own, they were _______.

A possibility I thought of is alien.

Comment: It's a bit too broad a category to nail down with a single word.

Comment: It would be helpful--and is actually required--to give an example sentence, with a blank for the requested word. You'll get much better results.

Comment: Edited it. Is this easier to answer? I'm having a little trouble explaining it.

Comment: Since you suggested "alien", consult a thesaurus (type "synonym alien" in Google) and see what you find.

Comment: ... another's ...